# vscode webview pass mesh data via postMessage

Tags: typescript, webview, vscode-extensions

I am writing a vscode extension to view some mesh files.

The HTML looks like:

```html
function getWebviewContent(context: vscode.ExtensionContext, panel: vscode.WebviewPanel) {
    const threejs = vscode.Uri.file(context.extensionPath + "/js/three.js");
    const threejsUri = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(threejs);

    return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
        <script src=${threejsUri}></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = init;

            window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                let [model, mesh_map] = event.data;
                console.log(mesh_map);
                console.log(model);
            });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2>3D model viewer</h2>
        </body>
        <div id="view"></div>
    </html>
    `
}
```

`model` is some YAML data about how the individual meshes should be interlinked, and `mesh_map` is `Record<string, Blob>`. The data is posted by the extension:

```
console.log(model);
console.log(mesh_map);
panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent(context, panel);
panel.webview.postMessage([model, mesh_map]);
```

The console log here works as expected. But inside the HTML, I can see only `model`, but `mesh_map` is empty. Does webview fail when the data is too large?

**Edit 1:** I missed mentioning above that I am receiving the mesh files in a for loop through socket:

```
var mesh_map: Record<string, string> = {};
for (const mesh_path of model.mesh_paths) {
    if(mesh_path !== undefined) {
        socket.emit('get mesh', { data: mesh_path });
        socket.on('mesh file', (msg) => {
            mesh_map[mesh_path] = 'dummy data';
        }); 
    }
}
console.log(mesh_map);
```

The console log after for loop works. So if I `postMessage` after the for loop, the object inside HTML after receiving the message is empty.